# How to solve this TypeError issue in python3? "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

Recently I switched from python2.7 to python3.7.3 In my project, very frequently facing this typeerror. `"TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"`. I want to define it as string only. I read to encode str objects in one of the posts. but it gives an error like "pass arguments to encode()", it is not working. Is there any permanent solution for this? like importing or defining something at the beginning only.

Thank You.
My code is as follows.

```
ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_ = ['A','B','X','Y','Z','W']
df = [None for i in ids]
print(type(df))
```

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: please provide the full traceback (and try to simplify your expression)

Comment: I think you also need to provide what is nk along with traceback.Also tell how to install nk if it is a module.

Comment: It looks like you are tackling a Python 2/3 upgrade without taking account of any of the tools that are there to ease the transition.  Take a look at `lib2to3` or `six` or `futurize`. Tackling the version differences on a line-by-line basis is a bad idea. Instead set up a deployment pipeline to convert you Python 2 code to Python 3. The conversion libraries will take care of most of the bytes/strings issues for you without your having to solve each individual problem on its own.

Comment: Provide a [mcve].  The code shown does not produce an error.  It prints `<class 'list'>`.  Also read this [Unicode article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) and this [Unicode presentation](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to convert a string object to byte object you should do something
like this

```
st = "Roushan" #  a string object
byte_object = st.encode('utf-8')
```

here byte_object is the actual object and 'utf-8' is encoding scheme
There are a lot of encoding schemes

ASCII

UTF-16

For more on types of encoding  [Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)

After this just figure out which argument was needed to be passed as byte instead of str and change that object to byte.

As i dont have nk module installed in my system i leave this to you

EDIT:

`open a fresh new empty python file`

write the following code

```
ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_ = ['A','B','X','Y','Z','W']
df = [None for i in ids]
print(type(df))
```

open a terminal and execute

 
python2.7 mycode.py

python3.7 mycode.py

in case 1 you get

in case 2

and please post the error Traceback you get . I believe the error is originating at other part of the code as this one is fine

Comment: same error, didn't work,   list_ = ['A','B','X','Y','Z','W']
for l in list_:
    l = l.encode('utf-8')
    print(l)

Comment: lis = [chr(i+65) for i in range(10)]

for it in lis:
    it = it.encode('utf-8')
    print(it)

Comment: This works on my machine. I hope you are using python3.x version. specifically i am using python3.6

Comment: I am using python3.7.3

Comment: can you give me a link to whole code cause this is getting exhausting